# AddNumber Function Trouble

Tags: c

I am having trouble understanding how to take the user input from my program and pass it into the function `AddNumber`. The program will start and ask for user input and will store it into the input array, but I am not sure how to take the information from the array and pass it to the function `AddNumber`.

I have updated the code, from what I understand my 'AddNumber' function doesn't do anything. I was under the impression that I created the pointer 'previous' should previous = NULL?

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

typedef struct A_NewNumber {
  struct A_NewNumber *next;
  char newNum;
} NewNumber;

NewNumber *AddNumber(NewNumber *previous, char *input){

//char input[16];
//double numEntered = 0;

NewNumber *newNum = malloc(sizeof(NewNumber));
sscanf(input, "%lf", &newNum->newNum);

//sscanf(input, "%s", newNum->enterNumber);
//numEntered = atof(input);
//possible code 
/*if (previous != NULL){
    previous->newNum;
}
newNum->next = NULL;
newNum->newNum = 0;
return newNum;

}*/


void PrintList(NewNumber *numStart) {
  NewNumber *currentNumber = numStart;
  int count = 0;

  while (currentNumber != NULL) {
    count++;
    printf("Number Position:%s\n", currentNumber->enterNumber);
    currentNumber = currentNumber->next;
  }
  printf("Total Numbers Entered%d\n", count);
}

void CleanUp(NewNumber *start) {
  NewNumber *freeMe = start;
  NewNumber *holdMe = NULL;

  while (freeMe != NULL) {
    holdMe = freeMe->next;
    free(freeMe);
    freeMe = holdMe;
  }
}

int main(){

   //indexNum = 0;
   char command[16];
   char input[16];
   //float userInput;
   NewNumber *userEnter = NULL;
   NewNumber *start = NULL;
   NewNumber *newest = NULL;

   while(fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin)){
    printf("Please enter a number->");
    printf("Enter 'quit' to stop or 'print' to print/calculate");
    sscanf(input, "%s", command);
    if(newest == NULL){
        start = AddNumber(NULL, input);
        newest = start;
    }else{
        newest = AddNumber(newest, input);
    }
    if( strncmp(command, "print", 5) == 0){
        PrintList(start);
    }else if( strncmp(command, "quit", 4)== 0){
        printf("\n\nQuitting....\n");
        break;
        //userInput = enterNumber;
    }
  }
  CleanUp(start);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should directly check the return value from `sscanf()`; that will tell you if the conversion was successful.  Also note that your '`strncmp()` calls mean the `printer` and `quite` will be treated the same as `print` and `quit`.

Comment: Minor issue: Note that "one-less" as in 15 or 16-1 is not needed in `fgets(input, 15, stdin)`,  just use 16 as in `fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without modifying your code too much, I would suggest that AddNumber takes a pointer to the previous NewNumber as well as the user input.  Your intent seems to be to read in `double`s as well so I'd modify the newNum field to be of type `double`.  Something like this:

```
typedef struct A_NewNumber{
    struct A_NewNumber *next;
    double newNum;
} NewNumber;

NewNumber *AddNumber(NewNumber *previous, char *input){

    NewNumber *newNum = malloc(sizeof(NewNumber));
    /* use %lf to read in a double */
    sscanf(input, "%lf", &newNum->newNum);

    if (previous != NULL){
        previous->next = newNum;
    }

    return newNum;
}
```

Then you can pass the previous and the input when you call the AddNumber function like

```
if(newest == NULL){
    start = AddNumber(NULL, input);
    newest = start;
} else {
    newest = AddNumber(newest, input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some problmes:

Code has no effect

```
if (previous != NULL){
    // Following line does no assignment
    previous->newNum;
}
```

Certainly after allocation, all fields should be set

```
NewNumber *newNum = malloc(sizeof(NewNumber));
sscanf(input, "%s", newNum->enterNumber);

// add
newNum->next = NULL;
newNum->newNum = 0; // TBD code, but set to something
```

Wrong pointer type to function

```
NewNumber *AddNumber(NewNumber *previous){
....
char input[16];
....
start = AddNumber(input);
```

Comment: I have updated the code, has this fixed some issues?

Answer (score -1):

There is usually a built-in way to get user input in most programming languages.  For example, in Java you can use the Scanner object to prompt for user input from the command line.  Is this a command line application?

This is C so I encourage you to use the scanf() function, here is a short snippet of how it works https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Simple_input_and_output#Input_using_scanf.28.29

you just have to provide the data type (i.e. %s for string) and a memory address.  This can be saved via a pointer and you can pass that to your AddNumber() function.

Hope this helps!

Comment: so in the sscanf() function I can say something like, sscanf(input, %s, &enterNumber); ?